# How to add a page to navigation history to prevent app from exiting?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic4

I'm still rather new to Ionic 4. I'm making an App that receives push notification. The navigation inside the app works like this:

```
Home page -> Detail page
```

Every time the user taps on the notification, the app will open and navigates to Detail page. The navigation works but since the navigation history is empty, if the user taps on the hardware back button, the app exits. I want it to redirect the user to Home page instead.

How do I achieve this in Ionic 4? is there any way to push a page to navigation history? I have read the documentation but couldn't find anything about this. The closest was probably `NavCtrl.push()` but it's no longer usable in Ionic 4.

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to take a look at the answer below?

Comment: I did, thank you very much! I have less than 15 reps so I couldn't vote it up. The other dev worked on it using your answer as a reference and manage to get it work :)

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) And no worries about the upvotes... I asked you because if the answer was helpful, you can mark it as the accepted answer and "close" this question. That way other users know that this was already solved and could focus on answering other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be an easier way to do this but the following approach is a very flexible one because it'd allow you to run any custom logic when the user wants to go back from the page shown after a push notification or a deep link is opened.

Please take a look at **[this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64485049?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**.

[image: StackBlitz demo]

Please notice that in the demo, I'm redirecting to the `DetailsPage` as soon as the app is loaded because of the following code from the `app-routing.module` file:

```
{
  path: "",
  redirectTo: "/details/1?fromDeepLink=true", // <-- here!
  pathMatch: "full"
}
```

Anyway, the important part happens in the `DetailsPage`. There, you need to handle what happens when the user tries to go back using a) the back button from the header and b) the physical back button from Android devices

The code is pretty self-explanatory, but basically in that page I'm looking for the `fromDeepLink` query string param, and if it's `true`, the app will register a custom action for both the back button from the header and for the physical back button from Android devices.

The custom action sets the `HomePage` as the root page, but sets the `animationDirection` parameter to be `'back'`. That way it'd look like the user is going back to that page even if we're actually adding it to the navigation stack.

It's important to notice that this custom handler is being removed as soon as the user leaves the page so that we don't affect the default behaviour of the back button in any other pages.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

import { IonBackButtonDelegate, NavController,  Platform,  ViewDidEnter, ViewWillLeave } from "@ionic/angular";

import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-details",
  templateUrl: "./details.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./details.page.scss"]
})
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit, ViewDidEnter, ViewWillLeave {
  @ViewChild(IonBackButtonDelegate, { static: false })
  public backButton: IonBackButtonDelegate;

  public itemId: number;
  public fromDeepLink: boolean = false;

  private unregisterBackButtonAction: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private navCtrl: NavController,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const itemIdParam = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("itemId");
    const fromDeepLinkParam = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('fromDeepLink');

    this.itemId = +itemIdParam;
    this.fromDeepLink = fromDeepLinkParam 
      ? fromDeepLinkParam.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'true' 
      : false;
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    if(this.fromDeepLink) {
      this.initializeCustomBackButtonAction()
    }
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    if(this.fromDeepLink) {
      this.removeCustomBackButtonAction();
    }
  }

  private initializeCustomBackButtonAction(): void {
    const leavingCallback = () => {
      console.log('Using custom back button action');
      this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home', { animationDirection: 'back' });
    };

    // Override the back button from the header
    if (this.backButton) {
      this.backButton.onClick = leavingCallback;
    }

    // Override the physical back button from Android devices
    this.unregisterBackButtonAction = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, leavingCallback);
  }

  private removeCustomBackButtonAction(): void {
    this.unregisterBackButtonAction?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Please also notice that by default the `ion-back-button` is not shown if there's no page before the current page in the navigation stack, so in the demo I'm setting the `defaultHref` property like this:

```
<ion-back-button defaultHref></ion-back-button>
```

I'm leaving it empty because the component is actually going to override what this back button does with my custom back button action. But the `defaultHref` needs to be added to the template, otherwise the back button won't be shown.